# Is it possible to use Ubuntu One with Webdav?

Tags: ubuntu-one, webdav

Is it possible to use Ubuntu One with Webdav ? In the `Connect to server` option. I didn't find a solution.

Answer (score 8):

WebDAV support is not on the current roadmap. It's an interesting idea and something that will be explored a bit further to see if it should be added to the next phase of development. Thanks for the idea!

[Follow the wishlist item](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-servers/+bug/396725) to keep track of the progress